# Using an input element to reference a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

bit of background: when a user clicks an element, it loads a form retrieved by an ajax call. I save a copy of the json in the controller, and when they change a value, it is to update the local json.
Let's say the json is something like this:

```
{
  name: "questions!",
  id: "0",
  questions: [{
    id: "1",
    text: "ninjas or pirates?",
    type: "radio",
    answers: [{
      id: "1",
      text: "ninjas"
    } , {
      id: "2",
      text: "pirates"
    }],
   }, {
     id: "3",
     text: "why?",
     type: "text"
     answers: []
   }]
}
```

the element returned is a jquery-ized version of the input that was selected.

While I could iterate through each field and check, I can't help but feel like there is a better way to do it and reference it more directly. How would this be done?

Comment: Not sure I understand the requirement. Can you create a fiddle sample that we can take a look at?

Comment: sure thing, this is a close approximation of what I am doing. Simplified of course. http://jsfiddle.net/a9G9T/1/
the differences: I am grabbing the json with an ajax call and saving it in my js then passing it to an EJS template and as the template is updated, I update my local json variable.
Basically, I want to find a way to make that `evt.target` at the bottom find an arbitrary spot in the json without checking every part of json in loops if at all possible. Notice how contact info, for example, is outside of questions. I still want to register and update that change in the json.

Comment: Couple of approaches. 1. I would add the question id to the input field you are creating. data-questionId will work. 2. Bring a library in like underscore. Based on $(event.target).data('questionId') you can find the element from the list of questions. If you don't get one, you know it does not exist, so you could add one to the collection. If you do find one, get the answers from the question, using underscore find the answer that matches the id and update it.

Comment: updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/a9G9T/3/ this is just a general approach. You can make it much cleaner with probably a question factory or a builder. But the idea remains this.